# Why are radio buttons disappearing with JQuery validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In advance, apologies for the amount of code. I wanted to present a complete picture.

MY PROBLEM: When the form is validated (using [**Jquery Validate**](https://jqueryvalidation.org)), the radio buttons disappear if the user did not select a radio button before sending. How can I fix this?

UUUHMM: When I remove the "required" from the radio buttons, the radio buttons do NOT disappear. You'd think "problem solved", but I do need that an message is shown when the radio buttons aren't used, and this does not happen then.

After checking on a windows computer I see that none of the messages are shown on a windows computer. What??? What am I doing wrong!? On a mac the messages are shown.

```js
autosize(document.querySelectorAll('#message_content'));


var validator = $("#comment_form").validate({
  ignore: [],
  rules: {
    gender: {
      required: true,
    },
    first_name: {
      required: true,
    },
    last_name: {
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      minlength: 3
    },
    email_again: {
      email: true,
      minlength: 3,
      equalTo: '#email'
    },
    message_subject: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    },
    message: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 4
    },
    hiddenRecaptcha: {
      required: function() {
        if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});


jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
  required: "This field is required.",
  remote: "Please fix this field.",
  email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
  url: "Please enter a valid URL.",
  date: "Please enter a valid date.",
  dateISO: "Please enter a valid date (ISO).",
  number: "Please enter a valid number.",
  digits: "Please enter only digits.",
  creditcard: "Please enter a valid credit card number.",
  equalTo: "Please use identical email addresses.",
  accept: "Please enter a value with a valid extension.",
  maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters."),
  minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter at least {0} characters."),
  rangelength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long."),
  range: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1}."),
  max: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}."),
  min: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.")
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Questrial;
  src: url(Questrial-Regular.otf);
}

body {
  background-color: blue;
}

div {
  font-family: Questrial;
}

input {
  font-family: Questrial;
}

text-area {
  font-family: Questrial;
}

span {
  font-family: Questrial;
}

p {
  font-family: Questrial;
}

form {
  font-family: Questrial;
}

html {
  text-align: center
}

body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: left;
}

#comment_form {
  width: 302px;
}

.label-radio {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #d8e3e6;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-family: questrial;
}

.inputfield3 {
  height: 33px;
  max-height: 33px;
  width: 302px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block !important;
  font-family: questrial;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.inputfield2 {
  height: 33px;
  max-height: 33px;
  width: 302px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block !important;
  font-family: questrial;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.textareafield {
  max-height: 350px;
  width: 302px;
  max-width: 302px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block !important;
  font-family: questrial;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

#g-recaptcha-outer {
  width: 302px;
  height: 72px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: -10px auto 20 auto;
}

#recaptcha-header {
  margin: 30px 0px -15px 0px;
  color: #d8e3e6;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  font-family: questrial;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  letter-spacing: -0.03em;
}

#contact_submit_button {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px auto 80px auto;
  width: 230px;
  height: 33px;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 157, 233);
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-family: questrial;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.requiredmark {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 295px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #d8e3e6;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.requiredmark2 {
  margin: -39px 0px 0px 295px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #d8e3e6;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.requiredmark-radio {
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #d8e3e6;
  font-family: questrial;
}

.error {
  display: none;
}

.error_show {
  color: red;
}

input.invalid,
textarea.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input.valid,
textarea.valid {}

label.error {
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  float: none;
  color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: block;
  font-family: Questrial;
}

​ #hiddenRecaptcha-error {
  margin-top: 65px!important;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  float: none;
  color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: block;
  font-family: Questrial;
}

​ .gender {
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block !important;
  font-family: questrial;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

#gender-error {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 0px!important;
  margin-top: 20px!important
}

.errMsg {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
  <script src="https://assets.webshopapp.com/photographycoursetour/autosize.js?2" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ 'iframeresizer-min.js' | url_asset }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://assets.webshopapp.com/photographycoursetour/iframeresizer-contentwindow-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <form id="comment_form" action="form.php" method="post">

    <div class="compulsoryfield">
      <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="Mr" required><label class="label-radio">Mr.</label>
      <input class="gender" type="radio" name="gender" value="Ms" required><label class="label-radio">Ms.</label>
      <span class="requiredmark-radio">*</span>
    </div>

    <div class="compulsoryfield"><span class="requiredmark">*</span>
      <input id="first_name" name="first_name" class="inputfield3" type="text" placeholder="first name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="compulsoryfield"><span class="requiredmark2">*</span>
      <input id="last_name" name="last_name" class="inputfield3" type="text" placeholder="last name" required>
    </div>

    <input class="inputfield3" type="text" name="company_name" placeholder="company name (if applicable)">
    <input class="inputfield3" type="text" name="customer_number" placeholder="customer number (on invoice if available)">
    <br>

    <div class="compulsoryfield"><span class="requiredmark">*</span>
      <input id="email" name="email" class="inputfield3" type="email" placeholder="email address" required>
    </div>

    <div class="compulsoryfield"><span class="requiredmark2">*</span>
      <input id="email_again" name="email_again" class="inputfield3" type="email" placeholder="re-enter email address to confirm" required></div>


    <input class="inputfield3" type="text" name="telephone_number" placeholder="telephone number (country code included)">
    <br>
    <div class="compulsoryfield"><span class="requiredmark">*</span>
      <input id="message_subject" name="message_subject" class="inputfield3" type="text" placeholder="subject of message" required>
    </div>

    <div class="compulsoryfield"><span class="requiredmark2">*</span>
      <textarea id="message_content" name="message_content" class="textareafield" type="text" placeholder="add your message here" rows="8" cols="39" required></textarea></div>


    <p id="recaptcha-header">before sending, please show us you're real:</p>

    <div><span class="requiredmark">*</span>
      <div id="g-recaptcha-outer" class="compulsoryfield2">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mySiteKey" required></div>

      </div>
      <input type="hidden" class="hiddenRecaptcha required" name="hiddenRecaptcha" id="hiddenRecaptcha">
      <br><br>

      <input id="contact_submit_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND">

  </form>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you try your snippet? It raised an error in my browser "myFunction is not defined"

Comment: @blackmiaool, I made an edit to resolve the "myFunction is not defined" issue. This however dis not solve my problem. Still the radio buttons disappear when the send button is used without first choosing a radio button.

Comment: How to reproduce your problem then? I tried to the "send" button but nothing happend. Can you provide a more simple demo and describe how to reproduce it?

Comment: Is there a reason for the <style> tag in your css file? 
`<style>html {
  text-align: center
}`

Comment: @blackmiaool, a the top of the form there are two radiobuttons for "Mr" and "Ms". Are you seeing that, when you do not select either of these radio buttons, the radio buttons are gone after using the send button?

Comment: @Eddy I clicked the "send" button without filling any part of your form and nothing happend. Maybe it's a problem bounding to your browser. I'm using chrome on windows.

Comment: @Tommy O, I have taken the style tag out. This does not solve the problem, but thanks, because It now centers the form properly.

Comment: @blackmiaool, strange. I am using Firefox, Chrome and Safari on a mac. All three produce the same problem.

Comment: When I remove the "required"  from the radio buttons, the radio buttons do NOT disappear. You'd think "problem solved", but I do need that an message is shown when the radio buttons aren't used, and this does not happen then.

Comment: After checking on a windows computer I see that none of the messages are shown on a windows computer. What??? What am I doing wrong!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you don't see your radio button is because when the radio input's have an error you give them the class "error". Which in the css you tell to `display: none;`. If you remove the class the element will be shown as you expected